# How to use Loft tool in Auto Desk (123 Design)?

Tags: sketchup, autocad, autodesk-sketchbook-pro, autodesk-inventor

I'm trying to make a 3D egg-like shape in Autodesk (123 design).
I'm using the loft tool to join 2D circle shapes.
When I do a few, it works, but when I select them all I get an "invalid operation" error.

I've been working on this for hours, and I can't figure it out! Any help would be much appreciated!